# Clustering MSDTC on windows Server 2008 R2 returns "No storage Available"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2, failovercluster, msdtc

I've set up a failover cluster, with SQL Server 2008r2, and it is running fine.  I want to cluster MSDTC as well, but when I go through the high availability wizard, it tells me that there is no storage available.  The storage node in the failover cluster manager rpoerts both the Quorum and the SQL Server cluster disks as online, and I can see them in Windows Explorer.  When a SQL cluster is set up, does it take the drive as exclusively it's own somehow, requiring me to add a drive specifically for MSDTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does it take the drive as exclusively it's own somehow, requiring me
>   to add a drive specifically for MSDTC?

Yep, it does, that's right, we certainly have separate MSDTC, Quorum and data/log/backup etc. volumes and it works a treat. Nice to see a question where someone's got the right idea before they asked by the way, makes a change around here :)